# Running DenseNet from cmd line and jupyter but vastly Different loss and accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch, jupyter

I’m running a DenseNet121 from Pytorch with the same exact code, same exact hyper parameters and same exact image sizes, once from a jupyter notebook and once using the command line via a python script. The notebook version gives me very good results (I have also cross checked this with the current SOTA and those results are in line with that) but the script version gives me very, very bad results. This isn’t about different results due to the randomness in the initialization - the script results are so bad, they simply cannot be true, based on my research. To get an idea of the difference:

- Notebook: accuracy on test set ~0.95, training loss ~0.14
- script: accuracy on test set ~ 0.62, training loss ~0.7

Does anyone have any idea why this discrepancy is happening?